# What is the proper way to have static files in one container and the webserver in another?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a webapp that I have dockerized, and I'm currently using nginx inside the same container to host the static files. However, this was only a temporary solution for development, and I'd like to use Caddy running in a separate container instead, with Caddy acting as a webserver that serves the static files in the first container.

To do this I need to remove nginx from my webapp image, but this introduces a problem: how do I keep the container running since there is no longer a running service within it?

I've found a few solutions such as using a command like `CMD tail -f /dev/null` to keep the container running indefinitely, but this seems hacky and potentially a bad idea in a production environment.

Or am I trying to do something that isn't really a good idea? What would be the suggested alternative if so?

Comment: "What would be the suggested alternative if so?" If you just need a place to store files, put them on a Docker volume (or bind-mount them from a local directory). See [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) and [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).

Comment: Interesting idea. So this image is part of a CI/CD pipeline, so it gets automatically built, pulled onto a server, and started from there. Would I be able to run the container without a service just to copy the static files to a volume, and then have the container automatically quit? And then Caddy could then serve the files from the volume?

Comment: You can use an ephemeral container (i.e., one that exits rather than running persistently) that just runs `tar` or `cp` to copy the files on to a volume...assuming those tools are available on the image.

Comment: A container is a wrapper around a _process_; if there's not a process to run, what happens with the files?  Can you use a static-file server in your main application instead of farming it out to a separate container?